# How can I add an admin template to a website without using a generic CMS as wordpress?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Is necessary to have a wordpress system in the backend to use an admin template? I see in the web there are many fancy web admin templates in bootstrap. I would like to use on of them but I'm not sure how to add one without using wordpress. Is there any documentation for it?
Thank you.

Comment: I am also doing a custom cms using laravel framework. So you should set your admin panel using you own code.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes you can!**

If you know PHP, you can use CMS frameworks like [Codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/) with administration library like [flexi-auth](http://haseydesign.com/flexi-auth/) and you can use any of those Twitter Bootstrap admin templates for your administration.